# how to convert Gstreamer command to C Code

Tags: gstreamer, amazon-kinesis

There is a problem converting Gstreamer commands to C source.

When I converted the Gstreamer command I was using into code,
it ran normally, but after adding the plugin, it does not run.

gst command is
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc name=src location="rtsp://127.0.0.1/rtsp" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse !
kvssink name=sink stream-name="" storage-size=32 aws-region="" access-key="" secret-key=""
session-token="" src. ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! audioresample !
audioconvert ! voaacenc ! aacparse ! queue ! sink.

my code is

```
data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("video player");

g_assert (data.pipeline);
data.rtspsrc   = gst_element_factory_make ("rtspsrc", "Source");
g_assert (data.rtspsrc);
data.rtph264depay = gst_element_factory_make ("rtph264depay", "Depay");

g_assert (data.rtph264depay);

data.videoqueue = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", "queue");
g_assert (data.videoqueue);

data.h264parse = gst_element_factory_make ("h264parse", "Decoder");
g_assert (data.h264parse);

data.capsfilter = gst_element_factory_make ("capsfilter", "Caps-Filter");
g_assert (data.capsfilter);
data.kvssink     = gst_element_factory_make ("kvssink", "Output");
g_assert (data.kvssink);

g_object_set (G_OBJECT (data.rtspsrc), "location", g_Url, NULL);

g_object_set (G_OBJECT (data.kvssink), "stream-name", streamName, NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (data.kvssink), "storage-size", size, NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (data.kvssink), "aws-region", RegionName, NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (data.kvssink), "access-key", AccessId, NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (data.kvssink), "secret-key", ScretKey, NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (data.kvssink), "session-token", SessionToken, NULL);

bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (data.pipeline));
gst_bus_add_signal_watch (bus);
g_signal_connect (bus, "message", G_CALLBACK (cb_message), &data);
gst_object_unref (bus);

caps_h264 = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-h264", "stream-format", G_TYPE_STRING, "avc", "alignment",G_TYPE_STRING, "au", NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (data.capsfilter), "caps", caps_h264, NULL);
gst_caps_unref (caps_h264);

gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (data.pipeline), data.rtspsrc, data.rtph264depay, data.videoqueue, data.h264parse, data.capsfilter, data.kvssink, NULL);

if (!gst_element_link_many (data.rtph264depay, data.videoqueue, data.h264parse, data.capsfilter, data.kvssink, NULL)){
}

if (!g_signal_connect (data.rtspsrc , "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), data.rtph264depay)){
g_warning ( "Err pad-added");
}

gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

g_main_loop_run (data.loop);
```

I added sound-related content, and it works on the command line,
but it does not run because it is implemented as source code.

I tried using the gst_parse_launch function,
but the error
GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 09:00:02.684: gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed occurs and streaming does not work.